# How to Avoid Class Conflicts in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my code we will generate dynamic divs according our requirement like number of appointments per day. Our main requirement is that on mouseover, we fetch the details of the patient for a particular encounter..

My HTML like as follows

```
<div class="schediv" id="1"></div>
<div class="schediv" id="2"></div>
<div class="schediv" id="3"></div>
```

And jQuery is written as follows

```
$('.schediv').mouseover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
    -------
);
```

It works fine for a single div but it doesn't work for multiple divs.

Comment: Please **please** NEVER use `$(this).attr('id');`, use `this.id` instead

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it didn't work".

Comment: use jquery.noConflict() function

Comment: $('div.schediv').mouseover

Comment: There is literally no information in the question that could help us identify the problem. Please provide a more complete code example and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. As already noted, also explain *what exactly* the problem is. What do you expect to happen and what does happen?

Comment: use id instead of adding actions to class if that what's your problem.!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to use `.on()` because you are addind DOM dynamically.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.schediv',function(){ 
   //code goes here
});
```

Comment: @Boaz really do you have evidence....and OP said "we will generate dynamic divs according"

Comment: Down Voter...please explain this massive amount of down-votes.

Comment: I downvoted because it is wrong. Also, flagged that last comment as offtopic.

Comment: @Doorknob so Sir kindly tell me why is that wrong.???

Comment: I didn't downvote, and personally I think there are too many downvotes. However, your answer is a very vague guess. There simply is not enough information in the question to give a solid answer and while "guessed" answers can be right, IMO, they are the most dangerous ones (as in they can bring the whole thought process into the wrong direction).

Comment: this code is working perfectly..

Comment: @user2281294: Working code does not equal good or useful answer. Here, I have working code for you too: `var answer = 42;`.

Comment: @user2281294 and yeah it should be....hey Doorknob now see...You better learning now before down vote or comment...Thanks...Look how quickly things can change....lol..

Comment: @DipeshParmar, gloating does not really demonstrate you have understood Felix's message. Perhaps this answer should have been a comment to begin with, as it is quite speculative (even though, I suspect, right on the money here).

Comment: @FelixKling yes i completely agree with you but OP has clearly statated in first line of his question that "**In my code we will generate dynamic divs according our requirement**"  so that is enough for us to see what will solve OP problem....

Comment: @DipeshParmar: IMO, no. He also says *"It works fine for a single div but it doesn't work for multiple divs."*. If all divs are generated dynamically, it should work for none of them. Maybe he is always selecting all elements and then uses some jQuery method which only works with the first element (like `attr` or `prop` or whatever). Again, maybe you are right, but the question really is too vague.

Comment: @DipeshParmar 5 downvotes was a little heavy, but getting your friends to all come and sympathy upvote you doesn't make this a good answer. You defo don't deserve 30 rep for this...

Comment: @Zenith what do you mean by "**getting your friends to all come and sympathy upvote**"...??

Comment: @Zenith you taking it all wrong bro...i keep it cause i knew this will solve OP problem so i was waiting for OP to confirm its working...nothing else...and Doubt about getting 4 uo-votes why don't you ask up-voter about this...Let ask SO about this...

Comment: @FelixKling, OP accepted this answer..

Comment: @user2281294: That doesn't change anything about the things I said though ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Its not like your working code although ;)